# How to get a button dropdown to change into a form/input? Example: 1-10 but if 10 is clicked convert button into input box so asto enter an amount

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
        <button>
            <select
                onChange={(e) => {
                    const buttonItemCount = e.target.value;
                    const numButtonItemCount = 
                        parseFloat(buttonItemCount);
                        onCartButtonChangeCount(x, numButtonItemCount);
                }}
                value={x.inCart}
            >
                <option value="default">{x.inCart}</option>
                <option value="0">0 (Delete)</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select>
        </button>
```

// I would like the button to turn into a form/input if user clicks on option 10+ [(here is example image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9wZM.png) .

```
    [button change from dropdown to form/input]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle some kind of state inside your component to know if the value is greater or not than 10.
Also, remember that inputs get values as strings, so you will need to parse them into numbers.

Something like this would do:

```
export default function TestApp() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSelected(e.target.value);
  };

  const parsedNumber = (v) => {
    return parseInt(v) || null;
  };

  return (
    <>
      {parsedNumber(selected) < 10 ? (
        <button>
          <select onChange={handleChange}>
            <option value="default"></option>
            <option value="0">0 (Delete)</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10+</option>
          </select>
        </button>
      ) : (
        <input onChange={handleChange} min={10} max={50} type="number"/>
      )}
      <button onClick={() => console.log(selected)}>Log current Value</button>
    </>
  );
}
```